# How to sort files by date created in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans-8

[image]

The files right now are arranged alphabetically? How to arrange them by date created?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot sort the files in a directory by date created, but you can sort the files within a directory by several other criteria. To do this:

- Click the **Files** tab.
- Expand your project and select the directory to be given a specific sort order.
- Right click the directory, and from the context menu select **Properties**.
- In the Properties window click the dropdown list for the **Sort Mode** property.
- Select the criterion to be used from the drop down list. The order in which the files in that directory are to be listed will be immediately updated accordingly.
- Click the **Close** button of the **Properties** window.

Here is a sample screen shot for the **src** directory of a simple Java application:

[image: directory properties]

Notes:

- You cannot set the sort order for all files globally at the project level. So if you wanted to list all the files in your project in (say) file size order, then you would have to individually set the **Sort Mode** to *By File Size* for every directory in the project.
- The description for **Sort Mode** on the **Properties** screen (as shown in the screen shot above) states "*Determines how the objects in the package should be sorted*", but that is only meaningful if the directory selected is a package. However, you can still select and sort non-package directories such as **nbproject**.